# Visibility into HttpURLConnection pooling?

Tags: java, android

I have been experimenting with [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) recently and am impressed with the fact that different instances of HttpURLConnection share connections from a common pool. (verified using packet capture)

My question is this: Is it possible to access the pool directly? I want to see what connections are there in the pool, status of each connection. Is there an interface to set maximum connections per host?

Also, is my understanding correct that any instance of HttpURLConnection across any thread/AsyncTask will always use a single pool? I only tested within a single task...

Java noob here and having a hard time navigating all the javadocs...

Comment: This is really an implementation detail and not part of the public API. Feel free to poke-around using reflection, but what you find is not likely to be consistent across JVMs or even versions of the same JVM.

Comment: So I guess I should stay away from it for the time being...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `http.maxConnections` system property (per the Android documentation -- didn't you read it?) to limit the number of connections per host. I don't know about querying for status information, though.

Comment: ok, that solves the "set maximum connections per host" part.... i initially didn't read their docs properly and assumed http.maxConnections is the total number of idle connections in the pool.... but my main interest is to see what those connections are...

Comment: Uh... `netstat`? This certainly isn't a part of the public API -- you're going to have to get down and dirty with reflection, a profiler, etc. There might actually be a JMX bean that exposes some of this, but I've nbever see it myself (nor have I actually looked).